Autohotkey: Cannot bind some keys with alt+win?
EDIT: I found the answer, see below.

I am trying to bind alt+win+key to window management commands. It's not working, and I am in the debugging stage, with the following simple config:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance
#!p::MsgBox "p"
#!+p::MsgBox "P"
#!y::MsgBox "y"
#!+y::MsgBox "Y"
#!f::MsgBox "f"
#!+f::MsgBox "F"
(...)

Now, these ALL work... EXCEPT:

alt+win+shift+P
alt+win+shift+M
alt+win+H
alt+win+shift+H
alt+win+S
alt+win+shift+S

WHY??
Remarks:

I tried using dvorak and qwerty. The limitations are identical.

I tried running the script normally and as admin.

I'm on windows 11.

I'd use other shortcuts if I could, but I can't.


I'm clueless.

EDIT
Never mind guys. I had a few shortcuts defined in PowerToys that I had forgotten about. My bad.

Not sure the cause, since some of those work in Clavier+, an AutoHotkey alternative. However, Microsoft has reserved some similar shortcuts, such as Win+Alt+Shift+Ctrl for Microsoft 365, and those cannot easily be overridden. In Win 11, they may have reserved yet more.

Thanks for your comment. I'm aware of the MS-Office hyper shortcuts being shoehorned into windows. But it seems very... random... even for MS to reserve only 2 or 4 out of 26 combinations. If they needed more system-wide shortcuts, surely they could've used another Win+key combination.

Try Nirsoft's HotKeysList, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hot_keys_list.html, to list all hotkey combos currently registered. Regrettably, it does not show what is the recipient of those keyboard hooks, whether Windows itself, a .lnk file, or a utility such as AuthoHotkey of Clavier +.

Rather than editing your post to add an answer, post an actual answer down below and then mark it as such. Maybe adding a bit about how you found it was these conflicting shortcuts would help make this helpful for others having similar questions.
